# simple while loop in r going into infinite loop

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm trying to write a R program to calculate the sum of a geometric series without using the standard formula as shown below:

```
h <- function(x,n){
    sum.value <- 1
          i <- 1
       while ( i <= n){
          sum.value = sum.value + x^i
      }
return(sum.value)
}
```

When I run this code, it goes into an infinite loop. I didn't have trouble when running it using a for loop. Its really strange that the same doesn't work with a while loop as is said that a while loop is more fundamental that a for loop. Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: You are not updating `i` inside the `while` so your stop condition will never get triggered.

Comment: If you know even a tiny bit of C, you could also write this to a `cppFunction` function with the `Rcpp` package.  It would be faster than written in R and is almost the same syntax. Although, Roland's vectorized solution is also very fast.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to increase `i`. Also I don't understand why `sum.value` starts with 1.

```
h <- function(x,n){
  sum.value <- 0
  i <- 1
  while ( i <= n){
    sum.value = sum.value + x^i
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(sum.value)
}

h(3,5)
#[1] 363
```

Of course, it would be much more efficient and simpler to use vectorization:

```
sum(3^(1:5))
#[1] 363
```

Comment: sum.value starts at 1 because the series goes like 1 + x + x^2 + ... but just now realized that can be implemented with i <- 0. I was under the impression that i will be incremented automatically.

Comment: What gave you that impression?

Comment: The for loop increments implicitly and so I assumed it would be the same for while also.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop in R increments automatically.  A while loop does not.  You need to add an increment to i inside your while loop if you want it to work.